# inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I count via sin(A) one X point in a circle and via cos(A) one Y. As a result I get one point on the angle A. Good. How could I count the angle A from X,Y? In other words, I have an object, and I want it turn in the direction to my point. I think using arcsin() and arccos() would work, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (with caution)

$$A = \arctan(X/Y)$$
Note: One usually associates X with cosine and Y with sine.

When calculating $\arctan$ you will have to make sure the answer is in the right quadrant. If not you may have to add $\pi$ or $180 ^\circ$.

The function $\text{atan2}(X,Y)$ will put it in the right quadrant.